# Transfer Files from SCO Unix to VirtualBox / VMware

Tags: linux, samba, sco

I have an old Unix SCO running some 5.06 version on some IBM hardware. I want to clone the hard drive into an `.iso` image so that I can use it in VMware or VirtualBox on a brand new machine. I want to try using Samba besides the `dd` command.

Have to use a serial cable and/or Ethernet card to try and establish IP connectivity between the Unix machine and my laptop and I am failing to pickup the NIC on the Unix box. I have tried several SCSI NICS to no avail.

How do I use the `dd` command straight to get a tar image of `.img` or `.iso`?

Answer (score 2):

I would boot the SCO box from a Linux Live CD, which will give you a running system, with network connectivity, independent of SCO itself.  Then you can do a dd of the filesystem and pipe it   through the network to whatever you want. Or mount a USB stick and dd it right to an iso on the stick, and then move it over to your new host. That might be less drama than trying to get a byte perfect dd across a network.